# Annotations for swagger-play

Tags: scala, playframework, swagger

Below is one of the controllers NameController, derived from a BaseController. The endpoint for the create method in the NameSpaceController is inherited from the BaseController. How do I annotate the create method in the BaseController such that each controller's Model Schema in the swagger UI is specific to that class?  Below I have included the NameSpaceController, BaseController, Model (Parent model) and NameSpace Model.

```
//NameSpace Controller 
@Api(value = "Namespace Controller")
class NamespaceController @Inject()(namespaceRepo: NamespaceRepository)
                                   (implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends BaseController[NamespaceRepository, Namespace](namespaceRepo) {

  /**
    * Retrieve all Namespaces.
    *
    * @return sequence of all existing Namespaces
    */
  @ApiOperation(value = "Get Namespaces", notes = "Returns all existing Namespaces")
  @ApiResponses(Array(
    new ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error"),
    new ApiResponse (code = 200, message = "Successful", response = classOf[Namespace])))
  def getNamespaces() = Action.async {
    namespaceRepo.getNamespaces.map(namespaces => Ok(Json.toJson(namespaces))) recover handleError(s"Error retrieving namespaces.")
  }

}


//BaseController 
abstract class BaseController[R <: Repository[_, T], T <: Model] @Inject()(repo: R)
                                                                          (implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext, formatT: Format[T]) extends Controller {

  /**
    * Creates a new entity.
    *
    * @return id of the new entity
    */

  //Create method annotations 
  @ApiOperation(value = "Creates a new entity", notes = "Returns id of new entity")
  @ApiImplicitParams(Array(   
    new ApiImplicitParam(
      value = "Create an entity",
      required = true,
      dataType = "com.bamtech.cde.hydra.api.models.Model",  //How can this resolve to the derived class? 
      paramType = "body"
    )
  ))
  @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error")
  def create() = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[T].fold(
      errors => {
        Future(BadRequest(JsError.toJson(errors)))
      },
      item => {
        repo.create(item).map(id => Ok(id.toString)) recover handleError(s"Error creating new item: $item.")
      }
    )
  }

  /**
    * Retrieves a single entity by its id.
    *
    * @param id the entity's primary key
    * @return the entity identified by `id`, or a 404 if the entity doesn't exist
    */

  @ApiOperation(value = "Get entity by ID", notes = "Returns entity identified by ID")
  @ApiResponses(Array(
    new ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error"),
    new ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
    new ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful", response = classOf[Model])
  ))
  def getById(id: Int) = Action.async {
    repo.getById(id).map {
      case Some(item) => Ok(Json.toJson(item))
      case None => NotFound(s"Item $id does not exist.")
    } recover handleError(s"Error retrieving item $id.")
  }

  /**
    * Updates the entity identified by `id`
    *
    * @param id the entity's primary key
    * @return the number of rows affected by the update
    */

  def update(/*@ApiParam(value = "ID of the pet to fetch")*/ id: Int) = Action.async(parse.json) { request =>
    request.body.validate[T].fold(
      errors => {
        Future(BadRequest(JsError.toJson(errors)))
      },
      item => {
        if (id != item.getId) {
          Future(BadRequest(s"Entity id: $id doesn't match payload id: ${item.getId}."))
        } else {
          repo.update(item, id).map(rows => Ok(rows.toString)) recover handleError(s"Error updating item: $item.")
        }
      }
    )
  }

  /**
    * Soft deletes the entity identified by `id`
    *
    * @param id the entity's primary key
    * @return the number of rows affected by the soft delete
    */
  def delete(id: Int) = Action.async {
    repo.setIsDeleted(id, true).map(rows => Ok(rows.toString)) recover handleError(s"Error deleting item $id.")
  }

  /**
    * Restores the entity identified by `id`
    *
    * @param id the entity's primary key
    * @return the number of rows affected by the soft delete
    */
  def restore(id: Int) = Action.async {
    repo.setIsDeleted(id, false).map(rows => Ok(rows.toString)) recover handleError(s"Error restoring item $id.")
  }

  /**
    * Maps a Scala Throwable to an HTTP status code, and logs the error appropriately.
    *
    * @param msg message to log and send back to the client
    * @return HTTP Result
    */
  protected def handleError(msg: String): PartialFunction[Throwable, Result] = {
    case e: NotFoundException =>
      Logger.warn(msg, e)
      NotFound(msg)
    case e =>
      Logger.error(msg, e)
      InternalServerError(msg)
  }
}

//Parent Model
@ApiModel(description = "Model", subTypes = Array(classOf[Destination], classOf[Export],classOf[Namespace]), discriminator = "type")
trait Model {
  /**
    * Gets the primary key for this Model.
    *
    * @return unique id value
    */
  def getId: Int
}

//Namespace Model[POST UI][1]
@ApiModel(value = "Namespace Model", parent = classOf[Model])
case class Namespace(@ApiModelProperty ( dataType = "Int")namespaceId: Option[Int], @ApiModelProperty(example = "ESPN", required =true)name: String, @ApiModelProperty (dataType = "Boolean") isDeleted:Option[Boolean] = Some(false)) extends Model {
  override def getId: Int = namespaceId.getOrElse(-1)
}
```

Comment: Try this library https://github.com/iheartradio/play-swagger, its easy to implement.